# Data saved in IsolatedStorage

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a question, I think very easy but I din't find the answer..

If in a first version of an application I have saved a string (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("mdpIso", "seti")) in the IsolatedStorage, when I will update this application to a new version will I have access to this data thanks to  IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["mdpIso"] ?

Thank you for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings will persist after your app has been updated to a new version.